# Conditions for my tower to be above the clouds

Tags: science-based, climate, geography, atmosphere, flora

I want to build a tower on top of which I should see clouds below.

Example: View from top to be right above clouds (even temporary low clouds are fine)

[image: Preferable view]

**Question : What conditions are required to get this view from the top of my tower?**

PS: Although cloud is preferred, it does not have to be literal clouds; fog, mist, or anything that gives the visual effect of a cloud will do.

**Assumptions to be made :**

1. The tower is on Earth
2. The height of the tower is no more than the Burj Khalifa (800m).

**OP opinion :**
I believe the following is to be considered but to what extent, I'm not sure :

1. Vegetation/Forest density
2. Height from sea level
3. Distance from sea
4. Surrounding geography

**Unnecessary extra info:**
A Sky Pillar(Pokemon) will be built in my alt-earth world as a pilgrim destination, in the mesoamerica region to change the native's human sacrificial tendencies, this sky pillar is required to be above the clouds.

Comment: I think you need to make the question more specific. I've stood on a small rise, while mist was spread below me. Mist and clouds only differ by one being connected to the ground. Because they are made up from the same droplets in the air it is possible to have clouds below you at any point it doesn't touch the ground any more. So Technically you can get that view with mist while being 2m off the ground.

Comment: I second Trioxidane by asking if a distinction between clouds and mist is important to the question; and if it is, then please explain what is the important difference. From the top of a tower it is common to see the ground shrouded under a veil of mist; and, from a definitional point of view, meteorologists classify mist as a very low cloud in contact with the ground.

Answer (score 2):

In wet/rainy weather, the cloud deck can be as little as 500 feet (~300 meters) above sea level, though it can be two or three times that thick.

That means *any* tower as tall as the Empire State Building, 1776 Tower, Smith Tower (or whatever it's now called, in Chicago), etc. in a coastal (or lakeside for a large lake) might see a cloud deck below the top floor observation deck -- or might be engulfed in cloud by the same overcast height.

In the case of ground hugging fog, much lower towers can look down on the clouds; I've looked down on fog banks from the tops of hills in Seattle, and those hills are only about 400 feet (~120 meters) above the harbor.  On those days, if I'd been at work on the 28th floor of a building (where I worked for a decade) that opened on Fifth Avenue (itself about 150 feet/45 m above sea level) I'd have been able to look down on a cloud.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to point out that atmospheric conditions vary wildly, even in the world's most consistent climates. The Atacama desert, the driest place in the world, often gets fog from the Pacific Ocean, many plant species depend on this fog to survive. No matter where you put your tower, you'll have days where clouds meet your conditions and days where they don't.

That being said, there are a few things you can consider to maximize your cloudy days.

**Cloud Base**

The cloud base is a meteorological measurement that defines the lowest height where clouds will form, if the atmospheric temperature reaches the dewpoint temperature and begins to condense into clouds. See https://www.windy.com/-Cloud-base-cbase for a map and forecast of cloud base, you can play with the map to get a sense of locations that often have a low cloud base, you're looking for zero meters AGL (above ground level).

**Planetary Boundary Layer**

To achieve a floating-above-the-clouds effect, you'll need an atmospheric boundary, or inversion, above which the temperature rises or the dewpoint lowers, so that the top of your tower is clear of clouds. The lowest such boundary you can count on (but not necessarily the lowest, depending on conditions) is called the PBL (planetary boundary layer), and can be anywhere from 100 - 1000 meters above the ground. See https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/planetary-boundary-layer for more information.

**Optimal Tower Location**

To get the most consistent results, I would suggest taking advantage of coastal fog, which can be very regular in some locations. If you put your tower on a relatively small ring of hills/mountains that circle a bay, and near a pass so that onshore wind is funneled towards your tower, bringing the fog with it, your pilgrims should be able to flock to the tower on cold mornings, being confident in the cloud effect.

This being fiction, you can also have your tower affect the nearby atmosphere, for example radiating cold, moist air and bringing the surrounding atmosphere down to dewpoint temperature, which could give your tower a "shrouded in mist" feel, if you're inclined to go that route. This is probably the only way to guarantee clouds, but you could also play into the unpredictability, where the cloud effect is seen as good luck, and if you visit the tower when no clouds appear, you're jinxed or cursed in some way.